# NSArray, last Object always invalid

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

This has got me stumped.

I build an NSArray and initWithObjects. The last element never really allocs. In fact, the next alloc in my code takes the same memory address as the one pointed from the last element.

Code is:

```
coordArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200.0,40.0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(56.0,290.0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(99.0,35.0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(222.0,333.0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(60.0,60.0)],
     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(105.0,299.0)],
     nil];
```

Debugger shows:

[alt text http://sergepress.com/temp/NSArray.png](http://sergepress.com/temp/NSArray.png)

If you have any idea, that would help.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce this error and couldn't. Could you post more of the surrounding code?

Comment: I can't say that the problem is in here... 
I added a [[[NSArray.... ]]retain]; to no avail.


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Waypoints : UIView {
 NSArray *coordArr;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *coordArr;

@end


@implementation Waypoints
@synthesize coordArr;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
  self.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; // transparent background
  coordArr =...;
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
 Waypoints *wpts = [[Waypoints alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
 self.waypoints=wpts;
 [self.view addSubview:waypoints];
 [wpts release];
}

Comment: - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
...the error appears here on the first line...
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont always trust the debugger, I have had many of times where the debugger is just wrong about whats in the variable, just like in your case it says invalid when it really isnt, so if i were you i would just output the number with NSLog and see if it outputs (it will).

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I hope you're right because these types of bugs certainly interrupt my workflow... what drew me to this point was that the app crashes while iterating through the array, at that value. Same goes when I use NSLog to read the class or value. I've since moved on to plists for the testing, but I'd be really relieved if I could understand this problem some day. Thanks again.